# Parallel login into angular and asp webforms

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, webforms

Currently I have an asp.net webforms application and would like to transfer step by step the websites to angular.
Now I would like to host two websites, the old asp.net webforms and the the angular application.
Now when I log into one website I would like to log into the other. The asp. Net application uses webform authentication.

I thought about to pass a encrypted login-key over the url or over http headers. But I am not sure of this is the right way, also for security. Beside this I don't know if this will work with webforms.

Comment: A simple solution would be to mount your angular app on any page within the webforms application.

Comment: How would this look like?

Comment: your aspx page will contain html and link to the angular's app.js

Comment: something like this example http://mahedee.net/introduction-to-angularjs-and-bootstrap-in-asp-net-web-form/

Comment: Ok I understand, but so I have to mix asp.net and angular. I would like to create an independent angular app, so that I can update and change it independently. The only thing that should work is navigate from angular website to asp.net website with logging in once...

Comment: Is your angular app going to be a node application or asp.net ?

Comment: Asp.net. But independent